# Question about the solution to the heat equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, special-functions, sturm-liouville

I was solving the heat equation in spherical coordinates with standard boundary conditions: temperature held at 0 at the boundary $r=\alpha$. I was able to find all eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. I'm not going to show all my work because it's unnecessary. I found that the eigenfunctions for the azimuthal problem are the associated Legendre polynomials given by
$$
P_{n}^{m}(\cos\phi)
$$
and the eigenfunctions for the radial problem are the spherical Bessel functions given by:
$$
r^{-1/2} \, P_{n+\frac{1}{2}} \bigl( \tfrac{\lambda}{a} r \bigr)
$$

So the solution will involve the product of these eigenfunctions:
\begin{gather} 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=n}^{\infty} A_{nm} \, r^{-1/2} \, 
P_{n+\frac{1}{2}} \bigl( \tfrac{\lambda}{a} r \bigr) \, 
P_{n}^{m}(\cos\phi) \cos(n\theta) \, e^{-(\frac{\lambda}{a})^2 \,t} \\
\qquad{}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=n}^{\infty} B_{nm} \, r^{-1/2} \, 
P_{n+\frac{1}{2}} \bigl( \tfrac{\lambda}{a} r \bigr) \, 
P_{n}^{m}(\cos\phi) \sin(n\theta) \, e^{-(\frac{\lambda}{a})^2 \, t} 
\end{gather}

My problem is I'm not sure how to find the coefficients $A_{mn}$, $B_{mn}$. I read that the associated Legendre polynomials are not always orthogonal so I think I won't be able to use them as an orthogonal system here. Could you please show what the coefficients would be for this solution? Thanks a lot!

EDIT.
Please help!

Comment: I think you wanted $B_{nm}$ as coefficients for your $\sin(n\theta)$ series, given your question that follows, so I corrected the typo. Please change it back if I've made this correction in error.

Comment: The heat equation is a time evolution equation, and so requires initial conditions. What are they?

Comment: The initial condition is a function of the 3 variables that we use in spherical coordinates

Answer (score 1):

If you are solving the heat equation within a sphere, and if you require the temperature on the boundary of the sphere to be $0$ for all time, then you know one solution is the temperature distribution which is $0$ everywhere in and on the sphere. Uniqueness will dictate that to be the only solution.